# Extending a pseudo-differential operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R}, e^x\,dx)$

Tags: functional-analysis, markov-process, semigroup-of-operators, pseudo-differential-operators

Let $A$ be a pseudo-differential operator with symbol $a(x,\xi)=e^{-x}\psi(\xi)$ where $\psi$ is a continuous negative definite function. It is known that $A$ is the generator of a self-similar Markov process that has $e^x\,dx$ as an excessive measure. If we denote the corresponding Markov semi-group by $(P_t)_{t\ge 0}$, it has a natural extension on the weighted Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R}, e^x\,dx)$. My question is the following:

**Can we determine the domain of the generator of $(P_t)_{t\ge 0}$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}, e^x\,dx)$? In other words, can we determine the $L^2(\mathbb{R}, e^x\,dx)$ extension of $A$?**

**An update:**
Also assume that $\psi$ is smooth. Can we find such a $\psi$ (which should also be negative definite) so the the operator $A:L^2(\mathbb{R}, e^x\,dx)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}, e^x\,dx)$ is bounded?

Comment: Do you mean $Au(x) = e^{-x}\mathcal{F}^{-1}[\psi \mathcal{F}[u]](x)$, is $\psi$ bounded, what is $P_t$, is it $P_t = \exp(tA)$

Comment: @reuns, yes, $Au(x)$ is that. $\psi$ is not necessarily bounded but $|\psi(\xi)|\le C(1+\xi^2)$. And indeed $P_t=\exp(tA)$. But you may assume $\psi$ to be bounded. I just want to know if there is any way to know the $L^2(\mathbb{R}, e^x\,dx)$ extension of the PDO.